# Leer archivo WAV y analizar muestras cada n milisegundos

Tags: c++

estoy comenzando un proyecto de reconocimiento de voz. Quiero trabajar con un texto leido en voz alta por mi, y luego introuducirlo a mi programa para que lo traduzca a texto ASCII.

Como estoy comenzado quisiera saber como puedo lograr segmentar la onda continua en fragmentos de n milisegundos de duracion.

He investigado y a eso se le llama ventana de tiempo, pero no he encontrado la manera de hacerlo.

Quiero hacer una ventana de tiempo para ver si logro conseguir los fonemas de la voz y aplicarles algún algoritmo.

Estoy trabajando con el lenguaje C++, si pudieran darme algun ejemplo en él estaría agradecido.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Qué librería de procesado de sonido estás usando?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster No estoy usando ninguna. Apenas voy a comenzar el proyecto. Yo voy a intentar leer el archivo WAV de forma directa usando un pequeño codigo en C. Está mal? Gracias.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Por favor dime más o menos como puedo atajar el problema del reconocimiento de voz. Algo así como una serie de pasos que haría un programa de ese tipo, si es posible. Al menos a lo que se refiere a lograr ubicar los fonemas en el audio por lo menos. Gracias.

Comment: C++ no dispone de lectura de archivos [`wav`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waveform_Audio_Format) de manera nativa, por ello deberás escribir tu propio interprete `wav` ([aquí](http://itk.ilstu.edu/faculty/javila/DataTypes/soundWav.htm) tienes datos del formato) o usar una [librería](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) que lo haga por ti. No hay nada de malo en usar C para ello, pero has etiquetado la pregunta como C++.

Comment: El formato wav no tiene compresión así que es más fácil de lo que parece. En la cabecera del fichero tendrás todos los datos que necesitas : frecuencia de muestreo y bits por muestra. El formato lo tienes en este [link](http://web.archive.org/web/20040317073101/http://ccrma-www.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/). Sabiendo el número de bits por muestra y el número de muestras por segundo, puedes saber cuantos bytes describen un segundo de audio, por lo que si calculas la parte proporcional podrás trocear el sonido como te interese. No soy experto en tratamiento de audio, pero lo poc

Comment: Gracias. Me parece bien tu solucion. La voy a intentar. XD Bueno, la idea era mi intento de aproximarme al problema. Seguiré leyendo para ver si lo consigo.